# Getting an exception for narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, c++98

I tried to catch a runtime_error for narrowed conversions but it is not working. I tried

```
int x= narrow_cast<int> (2.9); //I expected this to throw
int c=narrow_cast<int>(4200); // I expected this to throw
```

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Why do you expect `narrow_cast<int>(4200);` to throw?

Comment: What is `narrow_cast`?

Comment: Please let us know your implementation of `narrow_cast`.

Comment: Beacuse it says that in my c++ textbook. How would you suggest I would get an exception for narrowing?

Comment: Are you using `gsl::narrow_cast`?

Comment: If that is int x= narrow_cast<int> (2.9); then yes, if not No.